# Multiple Inheritance in C++, choose from which class take the member

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "A-F" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual void g() {
    std::cout << "A-G" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B: public A {
  public:
  void f() {
    std::cout << "B-F" << std::endl;
  }
};

class C: public A {
  public:
  void g() {
    std::cout << "C-G" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Now I want to define a class C whose member f is class B, and member g is from class A. Something like this:

```
class D: public B, public C {
  public:
  \\ Inheritate f from B

  \\ Inheritate g from C
};
```

How do I do it in c++?

Comment: why doesn't `class C : public B { ... };` solve your problem (provided you mark `B::f()` as an override)?

Comment: Ah, the fun of multiple inheritance. Problems like this are why other languages don't support it. There might be a better way, but I'd probably implement C::f to call the one I wanted.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not needed, as inheritance is transitive.

Comment: I realized I asked the question wrong, so I edited it. Sorry!

Comment: @JosephLarson I don't see a "problem" here. You have *two distinct base subobjects* here. I may not be what you wanted, but if so, the only problem is the misuse of non virtual inheritance!

Comment: @curiousguy My comment is from April 13 at 14:41. The OP edited the question the same day at 14:46, 5 minutes later. The original form of the question used multiple inheritance.

Comment: @JosephLarson The latest revision still uses MI (for class `D`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same if your `C` only inherits from `B`, i.e. `class C: public B {/*...*/}`. If you really want your `C` to inherit from both, `B` and `A`, you have to use virtual inheritance (see the `virtual` keywords when inheriging from A):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "A-F" << std::endl;
  }

  void g() {
    std::cout << "A-G" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B: virtual public A {
  public:
  void f() override {
    std::cout << "B-F" << std::endl;
  }
};

class C: virtual public A, public B {
  public:
};


int main() {

    C c;
    c.f();
    c.g();

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
B-F
A-G
```

Unreladed: I'd recommend to use the `override` (or `final`) keyword, especially when dealing with more complex class hierarchies.

### EDIT

As OP changed the question:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "A-F" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual void g() {
    std::cout << "A-G" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B: virtual public A {
  public:
  void f() override {
    std::cout << "B-F" << std::endl;
  }
};

class C: virtual public A {
  public:
  void g() override {
    std::cout << "C-G" << std::endl;
  }
};

class D: public B, public C {
  public:
  // Inherits f from B
  // Inherits g from C
};


int main() {

    D d;
    d.f();
    d.g();

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
B-F
C-G
```

as required.

**Note** That I am not a big fan of virtual inheritance and maybe there is a better solution for your problem. However, this depends on your exact problem.

Comment: I realized I asked the question wrong, so I edited it. Sorry!

Comment: @L.A. I changed the answer.

Comment: @I have another questio:

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "A-F" << std::endl;
  }

  void g() {
    std::cout << "A-G" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B: public A {
  public:
  void f() {
    std::cout << "B-F" << std::endl;
  }
};

class C: public B{
  
};

int main()
{
   C c;
   c.f();
   c.g();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've changed the question